# jquery-mobile on Windows 8.1 application (desktop) crashes

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-8.1

I'm developing a cordova application using jQuery-mobile (v1.4.5) and jQuery (v2.1.4).
Works fine everywhere except on Windows 8.1 desktop.

It results in: "An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in WWAHost.exe [2836]." when paging:

```
$(document.body).pagecontainer("load", url, {});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it has something wrong with your end curly braces. If you'd place an identity tag in between them, and providing this is all of your malfunctioning code, and that should do it.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it works: $(document.body).pagecontainer("load", url);